# implementation team - Inputs and outputs

Tags: engineering

I have questions regarding software development process,
Let's assume we have three teams

- Business analysts
- Implementation team
- Quality assurance team

I think that Business analysts inputs is BRD (Business requirements)  from the client, 
My question is regarding the implementation team  input (the engineers who actually code the software)
What is the input for the implementation team?

- What documentation for new requirement?  is if FSD? Functional specification?
- What documentation for a change request (client is requesting a system behavior modification )
- What documentation for bug fixes?

Is there a document template or a methodology to follow?
Does Agile cover this topic?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: As input, development team should get a new task/issue in their task/issue tracker. IMO, all methodologies suck (well, except [this one](http://programming-motherfucker.com/)), and writing "specifications" (as opposed to tests or formal proof of correctness) is *typically* just a way to pretend you're doing something.

Comment: As for agile's approach to this topic, while "agile" isn't a single unified method, most such methods suggest the use of cross-functional teams, I.e. all 3 groups you identify would work closely as part of a single team, so in this scenario your question is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your organization is not very sophisticated since you are asking these questions which are about how to manage requirements. Managing requirements is what makes or breaks a project.
You listed the three types of requirements.
Known Requirements -  (What the analyists provide) 
-- I would suggest finding a template on goodle and using it.

Discovered Requirements - (Change requests) 
Misunderstood or Missing Requirements - (Defects)
-- I suggest using a bug tracking tool like [Bugzilla](https://www.bugzilla.org/) for both change requiests and defects since defects are really change requests (Change what didn't work with what does)

Answer (score 0):

Agile does not provide suggestions. It is perhaps the best and most strict way of thinking about creating something. See the [Agile Manifesto](http://www.agilemanifesto.org/).

Agile is not a methodology. Methodologies are based on Agile.

However, Agile methodologies are very hard to implement and requires buy in from everyone involved in the project to succeed.